# Multithreaded recursive fibonacci with OpenMP Tasks

Tags: c, openmp, fibonacci

I know fibonacci is fundamentally sequential. But I just want to test OpenMP Tasks for the recursive implementation of fibonacci series. The following code in C works fine but my Problem is, instead of getting faster results with more threads, it gets worse. Why? You can try it on your self. I want best scalability.

Compile this code with "gcc -O3 -fopenmp -o fib fib.c" and run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

double serialFib(int n, double* a) {
        if (n < 2) {
                a[n] = n;
                return n;
        }
        double x = serialFib(n - 1, a);
        double y = serialFib(n - 2, a);
        a[n] = x + y;
        return x + y;
}

double fib(int n, double* a) {
        if (n < 2) {
                a[n] = n;
                return n;
        }
        if (n <= 30) { // avoid task creation overhead
                return serialFib(n, a);
        }
        double x, y;
#pragma omp task shared(x, a) firstprivate(n)
        {
                x = fib(n - 1, a);
        }
#pragma omp task shared(y, a) firstprivate(n)
        {
                y = fib(n - 2, a);
        }
#pragma omp taskwait
        a[n] = x + y;
        return x + y;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        double t0, t1;
        // To test scalability of recursive approach
        // we take N = 40. Otherwise it will take too long.
        int N = 40, i, nthreads;

        printf("Starting benchmark...\n");
        nthreads = atoi(argv[1]);
        omp_set_num_threads(nthreads);
        double* a = (double *) calloc(N, sizeof(double));
        t0 = omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel
        {
#pragma omp single
                {
                        fib(N, a);
                }
        }

        t1 = omp_get_wtime();
        for (i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
                printf("a[%d] = %.2f\n", i, a[i]);
        }
        printf("Execution time: %f\n", t1 - t0);
        free(a);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the eigenvalue/eigenvector computation for it. Way faster. ;)

Comment: What do you mean? I wrote this code on purpose. I don't want to calculate fibonacci fast. I just want to know why my code has bad scalability when I am increasing the thread count for OpenMP.

Comment: Hence the ";)" I was just making a little joke. "Very little, ensign."

Comment: How could it be quicker using threads? As each term is derived from the previous, it's not the kind of task that can be distributed to good effect.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But in case of the recursive implementation where I create many OpenMP tasks it should get faster with more threads. Because the recursive implementation calculates many numbers multiple times.

Comment: In the first place a recursive solution will be slower than the iterative one anyway, and you have answered your own question "why does it get slower" with your opening statement "fibonacci is fundamentally sequential." It is like asking "I know my feet are chained together but how can I run?"

Comment: But if you have more chains and more feet, you'll go faster because it'll take up more ground to hold them.....

Comment: You don't understand my question. I am asking why this implementation of recursive fibonacci with multiple tasks is faster when executed only on one thread and gets slower with every additional thread. I don't want to change the code above or improve it. I just want to understand OpenMP tasking.

Comment: I think there is a flaw here, and that you have several nodes calculating in parrallel the same terms.   By the way,   calloc (N+1, ...) as you'll use a[N]...

Comment: The last slides are telling exactly what I want to test. But I don't see the same scalability as in that pdf.

https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjSmaXQjPvLAhVIchQKHYlyAAIQFghNMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdoc.itc.rwth-aachen.de%2Fdownload%2Fattachments%2F3475434%2FOpenMP_Overview.pdf%3Fversion%3D1%26modificationDate%3D1389011156000%26api%3Dv2&usg=AFQjCNFyNXdQLoNmJoDqVv8oU7xmKyVHgg&sig2=ROdphcTWyWj5bO0luU-Rtw

Comment: I would have thought the `taskwait` would account for it. Otherwise, are you even even getting the right  answers, since the threads cannot run independently?

Comment: If you want to understand scalable tasking, I suggest you pick another topic to model, such as prime number calculation, which can be done independently, but even then, performs better when based on previous results (primes).

Comment: Yes, the answers are correct. Ah and true, forgot the N+1 xD

Comment: The taskwait is not avoidable I think because otherwise the x and y values are lost.

I just want to figure out how the guys in the link (I posted it 5 comments above) have managed to reach the scalability they showed in their slides. I want to verify and reproducy it on my own computer. That's all. I mean, I wrote pretty much the same code but it doesn't scale well xD

Comment: They haven't really reached scalability. In their slides they say "Don‘t create yet another task once a certain ( small enough )  n is reached". I think the example is to demonstrate the use of threads, not to achieve a practical way of calculating a Fibonacci sequence. In their graphs, the threaded solutions perform worse than the "optimal" trace, degrading rapidly the more threads are used. Which is what you say anyway.

Comment: Yes, but why is the code slower then when setting higher OpenMP thread count? According to their slides, it should get faster with each thread (up to 8).

Comment: Because the more threads you have, the more waiting is required. And the author has a different execution environment from you anyway.

Comment: This is a terrible implementation of Fibonacci. It contains both a data race and also false sharing, both resulting from the fact that values are being written to `a[]` all the way along the recursion tree and in the serial part. It will not scale and will get progressively worse performance with increasing number of threads.

Comment: @WeatherVane, the optimal solution on the slides corresponds exactly to the solution presented here and it really scales as expected, but the OP has destroyed the scalability by introducing the writes to `a[n]` at each step of the computation.

Comment: Ahhhh this makes sense! Will try out as soon as I can :) thanks

Comment: @HristoIliev Yep this is what I was looking for. It was really because of the writes to a[]. Without it, it scales very well! Thank you very much!

Do you have an idea how to fill the array a but without destroying the scalability?

Comment: Simply call `fib()` with `n` in the range from `1` to `N` and store the return values, although it makes little sense and will result in duplicate work.